# How to pass environment variable to a command passed to xmllint?

Tags: shell, sed, environment-variables

I'm trying to extract the `db` element's `value` attributes from an xml file using `xmllint`

My XPath Query needs to navigate to the correct dbtype, which I wish to store in an environment variable

Without an environment variable (hard coded), this command works

```
echo 'cat //rdbmsinfo/dbtype[@value="sqlserver"]/db/@value' | xmllint --shell "config.xml" | grep -v ">" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | tr -d \ | sed 's/"//g'
```

I am trying with below command:

```
echo 'cat //rdbmsinfo/dbtype[@value="$ldb_source_typ"]/db/@value' | xmllint --shell "config.xml" | grep -v ">" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | tr -d \ | sed 's/"//g'
```

where `ldb_source_typ` is a variable to get the value from shell parameter as `"sqlserver"`. But the above syntax is not giving any output.

Why isn't this working, and how can I fix it?

My config.xml XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdbmsinfo>
  <dbtype value="sqlserver">
    <db value="sqlsrv1">
      <dbhostip>192.168.0.1</dbhostip>
      <dbhostportno>2000</dbhostportno>
      <dbusername>sample</dbusername>
      <dbpassword>sample</dbpassword>
    </db>
    <db value="sqlsrv2">
      <dbhostip>192.168.0.2</dbhostip>
      <dbhostportno>2000</dbhostportno>
      <dbusername>sample</dbusername>
      <dbpassword>sample</dbpassword>
    </db>
  </dbtype>
  <dbtype value="postgresql">
    <db value="postsql1">
    </db>
  </dbtype>
</rdbmsinfo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with the following:

```
echo "cat //rdbmsinfo/dbtype[@value="ldb_source_type"]/db/@value" | sed 's/ldb_source_type/"'$SQLSERVER'"/g' | xmllint --shell config.xml| grep -v ">" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | tr -d \ | sed 's/"//g'
```

Which produces the following output:

```
sqlsrv1
-------
sqlsrv2
```

I didn't care enough to figure out how to make the value placeholder use an $ symbol, I may come back and edit it eventually.

Edit: here's one with a $, but you need to escape it with a :

```
echo "cat //rdbmsinfo/dbtype[@value="\$ldb_source_type"]/db/@value" | sed 's/\$ldb_source_type/"'$SQLSERVER'"/g'| xmllint --shell config.xml| grep -v ">" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | tr -d \ | sed 's/"//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

As I just found out, you need to set the environment variable between single quotes ( ' ).

So the following should work:

```
echo 'cat //rdbmsinfo/dbtype[@value="'$ldb_source_typ'"]/db/@value' | xmllint --shell "config.xml" | grep -v ">" | cut -f 2 -d "=" | tr -d \ | sed 's/"//g'
```